# create a mirror backup of subversion repository

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

I want to create a mirror backup of subversion repository.
For that I've followed the guide on [using svnsync to create a mirror backup of subversion repository.](http://www.cardinalpath.com/how-to-use-svnsync-to-create-a-mirror-backup-of-your-subversion-repository/)

I've successfully created the mirror backup of subversion repository.
However when I tried to automate the synchronization by modifying post-commit hook script it is showing

> Warning: 'post-commit' hook failed with error output:

I did exactly the same way they displayed but I'm not able to find what went wrong.

I googled a lot on this topic everyone are saying permission issues, end of line issues but still I'm unable to automate the synchornization.

---

Can someone explain how to create mirror backup of subversion repository?

Comment: What are the **exact** contents of `post-commit`? If you copied & pasted exactly from that linked blog, it's wrong - the final character should be an ampersand (`&`), not `&amp;` - the writer's blog engine didn't properly handle the HTML entity.

Comment: yes I've changed it to '&'.

Comment: Then `svnsync` probably isn't in the `path` of the user account executing `post-commit` (the user under which your server process runs). Specify the absolute path to the `svnsync` executable in the script.